# Joda Time classes don't have any constructors... why? And what am I doing wrong?

Tags: scala, constructor, jodatime, java, scala-ide

Apparently Scala on Eclipse tries to convince me that `DateTime`, `Period`, `DateMidnight` and many other classes in Joda Time don't have any constructors

Which is odd considering the fact that the documentation for them shows a constructor and a number of methods

The only things I have access to are the static methods such as `DateTime.now()` and `DateTime.parse()`

Note that I have added the `joda-time-2.2.jar`, `joda-time-2.2-sources.jar`, and `joda-time-2.2-javadoc.jar` files to the java build path of the project...

and yet whenever I try to make an instance of say `DateTime` Eclipse will tell me `org.joda.time.DateTime does not have a constructor`

So anyone got any idea why I get this error? And more importantly, how do I fix it?

Comment: tried in the console, work fine for me. Can you show some code?

Comment: @AlexIv the only real code I have is `val a = new DateTime()` which doesn't work 'cause it can't see the constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you need to add `joda-convert` to your classpath. Answer taken from [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10575).

If you're not using Maven or Sbt, you can manually download the jar from [its Maven Central page](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.joda%7Cjoda-convert%7C1.3.1%7Cjar). All you need to do is add it to your project build path.

Comment: also the answer you gave me specifies that I should get the Joda Convert jar file... which according to the documentation is used to convert objects to classes and back... how would that help me in any way?

Comment: try what? I don't even know what to do, it doesn't give any code examples all it says is to add the joda-convert library, it doesn't tell me how to use it or anything...

Comment: Well, just add it to your classpath! If you had read the linked article, you'd have seen that the Scala compiler expects to find all referenced class on the classpath, and one (or more) from joda-convert are missing.

Comment: I wonder why joda-convert isn't just in the joda-time zip from the get-go, that would have saved so much pain...

but yeah thanks this wored

Comment: Just as a heads up. You should generally trust @Iulian Dragos when it comes to compiler related issues. He probably wrote the scala compiler you are using :)

Comment: @cmbaxter, thank you but I can't take that much credit. I contributed to many parts, especially backend, but there are a lot of people who worked on scalac.
ElectricCoffee, no problem, the error messge *is* wrong and confusing. I assumed you're using some dependency manager already.

Comment: @IulianDragos I'm not using any dependency managers... I'm just coding in barebones Eclipse with the Scala IDE nothing fancy