# Compile errors when adding Joda-Time via sbt, but runs fine if I add it though my ide?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to get into the habit of using build tools. However, sbt is giving me some trouble, and I don't yet know enough about it to troubleshoot the cause of the problem.

I'm trying to add JotaTime as a dependency to my project.

My `build.sbt` in full looks like this:

```
name := "MyProject"

libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3"
```

Now, it seems to find the library and finish updating without issue. I can start using joda-time in my IDE. I can import the modules, autocomplete works, etc.. However, once I try to actually run the project I get these errors:

```
Error:scalac: error while loading LocalDateTime, class file 'C:\Users\myname\.ivy2\cache\joda-time\joda-time\jars\joda-time-2.3.jar(org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 10 at byte 42)
```

The exact code in question is this:

```
def main(args: List[String]) = {
    println(new LocalDateTime(System.currentTimeMillis))
}
```

To try and troubleshoot this a bit. I removed the dependency line from the `build.sbt` and instead downloaded and added the `jota-time` library manually via my IDE (version 2.3, just as in the build file), and everything works A-OK. No errors. Everything compiles and runs.

What would be causing the version of JodaTime that sbt downloads to be broken?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class broken error with Joda Time using Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856266/class-broken-error-with-joda-time-using-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.6"
```

Or write this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "joda-time" % "joda-time"    % "2.3"
                           , "org.joda"  % "joda-convert" % "1.6"
                           )
```

Whichever style is up to you, but that should fix it.

Joda-Time requires Joda-Convert to work in Scala, don't ask me why, it just does.

Look [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721927/joda-time-classes-dont-have-any-constructors-why-and-what-am-i-doing-wrong)] for more info

Comment: The same applies when using the Maven Scala Plugin by the way.

Comment: You can find explanation in [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/upgradeto230.html) documentation `Joda-Time uses annotations from Joda-Convert.
In the Java programming language, this dependency is optional, however in Scala it is not.
Scala users must manually add the Joda-Convert v1.2 dependency.`

Comment: @adjablon that's the explanation I forgot about

Comment: As a recommendation, instead of using JodaTime directly try to use nscala-time (https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time). It's a very nice JodaTime wrapper for Scala.